# nextjs 13 jsconfig.json custom path for folder inside components throws error on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm using Next.js as:

```
version 13.4.4
eslint: on
app directory: yes
server components: yes
js or ts: js
```

in my `jsconfig.json` I've set a path shortcut for my `components` folder which is located inside `/src`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["./src/components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

this works fine for files directly into **/components** , as:

```
import Hero from '@/components/Hero'
```

but then I created a subfolder as **/components/sections/** , inside sections I have a component **Hello.js** which I'm importing on my homepage as:

```
import Hello from '@/components/sections/Hello'
```

this is the same process I used before on Next.js 12 but with the version 13.4.4 when I deploy on Vercel the deploy fails with error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve '@/components/sections/Hello'

why?

Comment: what version of typescript you're using

Comment: Two questions. Is it working locally? Did you override the default Root Directory or Output Directory settings in Vercel?
Following your instructions, I built and deployed an app to Vercel with the same jsconfig and component structure and it works. https://test-non-default-alias.vercel.app/

Comment: yes and no, and 5 more characters for stackoverflow

Answer (score -2):

Copy-Paste this code in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["./components/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["./assets/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```